# Prove the size of a linear transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that the size of a linear transformation matrix going from $R^k$ to $R^{p}$ is a $p*k$ matrix.  Assuming $ p,k \geq 1$. I can prove it for fixed values of $p$ and $k$ but I am looking for a general proof.  I tried finding the linear transformation between two arbitrary matrices but didn't get anywhere useful.

Is there a general proof available?

Comment: Necessarily you need M be p*k in order you have M(v) = w in $R^p$ (if you want to deduce it take any base of $R^k$ and use linearity

Answer (score 1):

Try choosing a basis for $T$ in $\mathbb R^k$: then each basis vector in $\mathbb R^k$ will be transformed into a vector in $\mathbb R^p$. Now, there are $k$ vectors in a basis for $\mathbb R^k$, and each will have an image $T(v)$ in $R^p$, consisting of $p$ entries, i.e., $p$ Real numbers, a $p$-ple of Real numbers. This gives you a total of $p \times k$ entries, as $k$ columns, each column having $p$ Real numbers as entries as $T(v)$.

As an example, for $T: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 $ linear, after choosing a basis {$v_1, v_2, v_3$} for $T$, you will get $T(v_i)=w_i$, where $(w_{i1}, w_{i2})$ is a pair of Real numbers. Do this for each of $v_, v_2, v_3$, and you will get a matrix where there are $3$ columns (one for each of $v_1, v_2, v_3$), consisting each of a pair of Real numbers, giving you a $ 2 \times 3$ matrix.